# Infinite recursion when using subcomponent for encapsulation

Tags: dagger

I'm trying to achieve encapsulation by using subcomponent which is described [here](https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents), but I got infinite recursion.

Here is my code:

```
//tried adding @ScopeA, still the same.
public class A {
    @Inject
    A(B b) {

    }
}
```

```
@ScopeA
public class B {
    @Inject
    B() {

    }
}
```

```
@Component(modules = AModule.class)
@Singleton
public interface AComponent {
    public A a();
}
```

```
@Module(subcomponents = SComponent.class)
class AModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    A a(SComponent.Factory factory) {
        return factory.component().a();
    }
}
```

```
@Subcomponent
@ScopeA
interface SComponent {
    @ScopeA
    A a();
    @Subcomponent.Factory
    interface Factory {
        SComponent component();
    }
}
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DaggerAComponent.create().a();
    }
}
```

After checking generated dagger code, I found this:

```
  private final class SComponentImpl implements SComponent {
    private SComponentImpl() {}

    @Override
    public A a() {
      return DaggerAComponent.this.aProvider.get();
    }
  }
```

It seeems that SComponent are getting `A` from parent component, which is not what I wanted, where is the problem of my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the example from the Subcomponents for Encapsulation page uses a [qualifier annotation](http://javax-inject.github.io/javax-inject/api/javax/inject/Qualifier.html), `@PrivateToDatabase`, which is not a scoping annotation and which distinguishes the binding of `Database` from the binding of `@PrivateToDatabase Database`.

Subcomponents inherit all of the bindings from their parent components, so you currently do have A available from the parent component and also A available from the subcomponent. This is especially tricky if anything in your subcomponent needs to inject A, if it weren't marked `@Singleton`: Do you want the A from the parent component, or the A from the subcomponent?

Another tricky part of this situation is that you can't use qualifier annotations on classes that use `@Inject` constructors.

I'd recommend that you do the following:

1. Extract an interface from A, so then you have A and AImpl.
2. Keep your `@Provides` method that gets an A instance from the subcomponent.
3. Have the subcomponent expose AImpl, and (to best avoid ambiguity) only inject AImpl in the classes in your subcomponent, not A.

If you'd rather not extract an interface, you could also work around this problem by removing `@Inject` from A and writing a `@Provides` method in a module in the subcomponent that returns a qualified A, so the unqualified A goes through the top-level component and the qualified A is only available within the subcomponent.

Comment: Just looking at the Dagger 2 examples it's quite easy to see this was someone's side project then Google decided to make it something useful and it blew on their face. Haven't found a proper explanation even in the documentation, the best you can find is a coffeemaker example that author themselves don't know what they were doing.

Comment: @Farid What explanation are you looking for? Subcomponents have been in Dagger 2 since [February 2015](https://github.com/google/dagger/commit/959f5cd1c8ab1aa4eef701301b3363a8b6c10ca6), before Dagger 2 was even released, and the concept of using additional Modules to add bindings to an existing Injector has been [a part of Guice since 2.0](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/2.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#createChildInjector(java.lang.Iterable)). Subcomponents also power [dagger.android](https://dagger.dev/android) and [Hilt](https://dagger.dev/hilt/subcomponents-vs-deps).